# gulp add folder in zip archive

Tags: gulp, zip

```
gulp.task( 'zip', function () {
  return gulp.src( './dist/**' )
  .pipe(zip( 'dist.zip' ))
  .pipe(gulp.dest( './' ));
});
```

I have next structure

```js
dist.zip
  all-files
```

How do I make the following structure in the archive?

```js
dist.zip
 dist
   all-files
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine except for the `gulp.dest` which takes a string (or a function):

```
gulp.task( 'zip', function () {
  return gulp.src( './dist/**' )
  .pipe(zip( 'dist.zip' ))

  //  .pipe(gulp.dest( ./ ));  your code, note the apostrophes below

  .pipe(gulp.dest( './' ));

});
```